# relational database design, one meta table for several tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

i do not know much about database design, recently i got a project that promises to need a huge database and i'm confused about what is the best way of designing an standard database structure(mysql).

for example let's say we have 3 tables: users,shops,products
each of these(users,shops,products) may have one or several details, like social page links(for shops),phone numbers(for users), addresses(for shops and users), colors\materials(for products),etc...

should i create only one meta table and store all of the details in it or should i create separate meta tables for each table?(user_meta,shop_meta,product_meta).
which one is a better approach?

any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

according to mr Branko Dimitrijevic every table should have it's own meta table.

my problem is that user may have several types of details like: social pages url, user addresses,user role, etc...

is it ok to design database like this:

```
**Table: USERS**

userId | username | email | pass


**Table: USERS_META**

userId | metaType | metaValue
```

metaType will be the different types of details user can have like address,instagram page,facebook page,etc...

for example records in USERS_META table would be like:

```
userId |   metaType   |       metaValue
---------------------------------------------------
2      |  address     | some address for user home
---------------------------------------------------
2      |  role        | 1(id of the role)
---------------------------------------------------
2      |  instagram   | instagram.com/userpage
---------------------------------------------------
3      |  address     | some address for user 3 home
---------------------------------------------------
3      |  facebook    | facebook.com/userpage
---------------------------------------------------
3      |  role        | 2(id of the role)
---------------------------------------------------
2      |  age         | 18
---------------------------------------------------
3      |  age         | 19
```

now if i want the address of user 2:

```
SELECT metaValue FROM USERS_META WHERE userId=2 AND metaType='adress'
```

and if i want users social pages link:

```
$array=array('facebook','instagram','telegram','etc');
SELECT metaValue FROM USERS_META WHERE userId=2 AND metaType IN($array)
```

is this a good way or should i create separate tables for each meta(USER_ADDRESSES,USER_SOCIAL,USER_AGE,etc...)?

Comment: one meta table? I wouldn't mix the data from user (phone numbers) with the data from products (colors/materials) ... it doesn't make any sense

Comment: something like meta_id(for user_id,shop_id,product_id), meta_key(user_phone_number) and meta_value(12345) and then select meta_value from meta_table were meta_key=user_phone_number and meta_id=user_id.

Comment: You are not clear. What do you mean, "meta table"? Please give details of your tables & colums, queries and example data. Please edit your question, comments are not for clarifications. Read an intro to information modeling & database design, and read about problems with EAV which essentially stores metadata & data instead of data that the DBMS can actually manage.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell: you shouldn't "merge" multiple tables.

Even if they happen to have same fields, they almost certainly don't have same *constraints* (e.g. foreign keys pointing to them from other tables).